# 419 error on every post route in laravel v7.0 and php v7.2

Tags: laravel-5

I am working on laravel project I have to face a 419 error on every post route. I have checked the CSRF token  I have attached with every form. anyone can help me why this occurs.

Laravel version 7.0
PHP version 7.2
PHP version 7.3 on server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete **Vendor** file and run command in terminal composer update

it was work for me!
[image]